# Старый запрос в PDO

Tags: pdo, php

Есть примерно такой код

```
$cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($cat)) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Как его переделать в PDO и правильно ли я его переделал?

```
$this->db = new PDO(ляляля);

$cat = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `blog`");
while($row = $this->db->fetchObject()) {
    echo $row->title;
}
```

или что я не так делаю с fetchObject?
и какой аналог в pdo mysql_fetch_object?

Comment: Кто из поисковика, вот ответ на вопрос

http://rubphp.blogspot.ru/2011/06/pdo-php-data-objects.html?showComment=1377994669779#c7876278841058262623

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем правильно:

надо `$cat` (ресурс результата) опрашивать, типа вот так:

```
$cat = $connect->query($sql);

if ($cat && ($result->rowCount() > 0))
{
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $cat->fetchObject()) {
//....
}
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6401591

Comment: ок, разобрался

пишу класс для работы с pdo и mysqli

в общем при смене драйвера код в проекте не должен ломаться

так что вот так должно быть, уже сделал

    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `users`;");
    while($row = $this->db->fetch_object()) {
      echo $row->id;
      echo $row->login;
    }

p.s. естественно нужно вначале подключить мой класс, так работать не будет

Comment: а зачем вам отдельный класс то ? если не собираетесь городить что-то типа ActiveRequest, то ваша затея не удастся. ну и непонятно, почему $this->db а не $this->fetch_object() в таком случае.

Comment: @eicto, видел где-то еще подобное, там инстанс PDO хранится в статическом атрибуте класса ОRМ-модели, по факту для каждого класса свой.